# Map new features in geoJSON source

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have a liitle project in Mapbox with several geoJSON files loaded via map.addSource.

I would like to extend its information with new properties based in other parameters (for example, a separated month property based on date, to be able to set a filter).

Can this be done with Mapbox GL JS? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to load a GeoJSON file, then modify it, before displaying it on a Mapbox map.

The easiest way to do this is to load it yourself, for instance using D3-request's `.json()`, rather than getting Mapbox to fetch it for you:

```
d3.json('mydata.geojson', (error, data) => { 
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        data.features.forEach(f => f.properties.month = f.properties.date.match(...));
        map.addSource('mydata', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, looks good!! But it doesn't seem to get along well with my code... :( If I do it only for one of my JSON file it loads perfectly, but when I load several of them inside a for loop, it throws an "Error: There is already a source with this ID" error, with seems impossible to me.

Comment: I have solved using d3.query for the sources, and then your method to map de properties. Thanks a lot!!